# Drupal 7 admin for client, each menu for each content type

Tags: drupal, menu, admin

I want create an admin interface for my client. For now if my client wants to add an "article", he needs to click "content" link in the menu, then click "add content", then select "article" content type, then add it. This is not friendly.

I want to have "article", "photo", "video" ( all these are my content type ), each as one menu link in the admin. And if the user clicks "article", it will show a list of all articles, so one does not need to use "type filter" to filter the content type, and user can click "add" link in this list view directly to add each content type.

How can I do that? Thanks of help.

Answer (score 1):

Though this might not be exactly what you're looking for, look into using the [Total Control](https://drupal.org/project/total_control) module. It basically creates an admin dashboard where everything is easily accessible.